# Job only working once, then returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a background job that's job is essentially to wait for a users response. Then do a certain action depending on their reply.

```
class AwaitDriverReply
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(order_id)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      order = Order.find_by(id: order_id)
      10.times do
        if order.accepted == true
          puts "driver confirmed"
          break
        elsif order.accepted == false
          puts "driver has declined"
          break
        else
          puts "awaiting response"
          sleep(1)
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

the reason why I have to sleep it is because the user can obviously answer at different times, and this one waits ≈ 10 seconds. Now this works perfectly the first time I run this job, then if I try to repeat it, the job returns an error, which I haven't been able to debug:

```
2016-02-22T16:34:52.096Z 1431 TID-ovpfin8kg WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `accepted' for nil:NilClass
2016-02-22T16:34:52.096Z 1431 TID-ovpfin8kg WARN: /Users/Sebastian/workspace/ex/app/jobs/await_driver_reply.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/Users/Sebastian/workspace/ex/app/jobs/await_driver_reply.rb:10:in `times'
/Users/Sebastian/workspace/ex/app/jobs/await_driver_reply.rb:10:in `block in perform'
/Users/Sebastian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0-preview2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/Users/Sebastian/workspace/ex/app/jobs/await_driver_reply.rb:6:in `perform'
```

and it returns undefined method accepted for nil, which usually means the order doesn't exist. However I added a `puts` that inspected the order, and it's there.

Comment: Why doesn't it on having accepted set to true or false queue the job to do whatever you want it to do rather than polling the database to see if it's changed?

Comment: Because I also want to check for no input, and give it a restriction to say 10 sec.

Comment: please show the code where you are inspecting the the `order` and the matching debug log. if this is the actual code, there is no chance that the order can be not nil.